# Проблемы с кодировкой кириллицы в пути

Tags: java, кодировка

`.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString()`
Используя такую конструкцию я получаю путь до jar файла в виде String, но если в пути будет содержаться что-то с кириллицей, то возникают проблемы с кодировкой, и получается это `%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9`, вместо слова на русском.
Подскажите, как я могу избежать этих проблем или же преобразовать строку в нормальную.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent("%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b3")`

Answer (score 0):

В общем нашёл метод `URLDecoder.decode(String, Charset)`, в который можно поместить строку и указать кодировку и он вернёт раскодирует строку.